# Filter results within groups sql

Tags: sql, sqlite

In the table below, I want to know *how many customers ordered lunch without a coffee*. The result would be 1, for sale ID 300, because two lunches were ordered but only one coffee.

It’s been 8 years since I last used SQL! How do I say “group the records by sale ID and for each group, drop groups where there is no lunch or COUNT(coffee) < COUNT(lunch)"?

| SALE ID | Product |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | coffee |
| 100 | lunch |
| 200 | coffee |
| 300 | lunch |
| 300 | lunch |
| 300 | coffee |

Comment: Why did you accept an answer that does not return your expected results: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=5854ac763387fc64df876b51628826e6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is one way:

```
select count(*) from (
   select saleID 
   from tablename
   group by saleID
   having sum(case when product ='coffee' then 1 else 0 end) = 0 
   and sum(case when product ='lunch' then 1 else 0 end) = 1
) t
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with aggregation and the conditions in the HAVING clause.

This query:

```
SELECT sale_id
FROM tablename
GROUP BY sale_id
HAVING SUM(product = 'lunch') > SUM(product = 'coffee');
```

returns all the `sale_id`s that you want.

This query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(*) OVER () counter
FROM tablename
GROUP BY sale_id
HAVING SUM(product = 'lunch') > SUM(product = 'coffee');
```

returns the number of `sale_id`s that you want.

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=90c674b8231f9c723db5ce512fb3441b).

Answer (score 1):

```
select count(*) from (
  --in this subquery calculate counts and ignore items that haven't any lunch
   select 
    saleID, sum(case when product ='coffee' then 1 else 0 end) as coffee,
    sum(case when product ='lunch' then 1 else 0 end)  lunch
   from tablename
   group by saleID
   having sum(case when product ='lunch' then 1 else 0 end) >= 1  --Here we are ignoring all items haven't any lunch
) t
where lunch > coffee -- we check second condition be ok
```